# Markov's Inequality and upper bounds

Tags: probability

I looked through previous posts of Markov's inequality here - [Markov’s inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822301/markov-s-inequality?newreg=2ac8fb1c98bb4d94965a8ca75ce95d98) but it doesn't help me answer my question. Please any help is appreciated.

Modify $X$ and apply Markov's inequality to upper bound $P(X≥3)$ when

$1. X ≥ 2$ and $E[X] = 2.5$

$2. X ≥ 0$ and $E[X^2] = 5$

Markov's inequality says $P(X\ge a) \le \frac{\mu}{a}$

For problem 1, I assumed the answer is $\frac{2.5}{3}$ but that answer is incorrect.

Not even sure how to tackle problem 2.

Comment: You need to look at the proof of Markov's inequality. It's  very short and very simple. This should clear things up. This proof is simplest to understand https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse312/12sp/section/section_5.pdf

Comment: The trick here is to apply Markov's inequality to some other random variable $Y$ related to the $X$ of interest.  Convert the target $P(X\ge3)$ into a statement of form $P(X\ge3)=P(Y\ge a)$ and bound that probability with $\mu/a$, where $\mu = EY$ not $EX$.

Comment: I still don't see the simple explanation from the proof.  Please advise. I have spent hours on this and it still isn't clear.

Comment: Markov's inequality holds only for nonnegative random variables.  For problem 1, since $X\geq 2$, it is nonnegative and indeed your bound $P[X\geq 3] \leq E[X]/3 = 2.5/3$ holds true.  However, this would be true even if you were only told $X\geq 0$.  Since you are told $X\geq 2$, you can get a better bound by defining a convenient $Y\geq 0$ in terms of $X$, as in Kimchi Lover's comment.  For problem 2, just define $Y=X^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured this out.